# Simpy Store - Dependent Events

Tags: python, simpy

I'm trying to model situations where getting something from a store is dependent upon something else.

Let's say I have a producer that is putting items into a limited capacity store S1.  These items get shifted into a another store, S2, if and only if (1) there is an item in S1 *and* there is room in S2.

P -> S1 -> S2

The problem is that I need the removal of an item from S1 to be conditioned on there being space in S2.

In code:

```
from simpy import *

env = Environment()
S1 = Store(env, capacity=1)
S2 = Store(env, capacity=1)

def producer():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield S1.put(i)
        print("Producer put item: %s"%i)
        i += 1

def s1_to_s2():
    while True:
        item = yield S1.get()
        yield S2.put(item)

env.process(producer())
env.process(s1_to_s2())
env.run(until=20)
```

which produces

```
Producer put item: 0
Producer put item: 1
Producer put item: 2
```

The way I've modeled this makes it look like there's 1 extra storage slot between S1 and S2, which I don't want.  Since I have 2 storage units, each with capacity 1, the producer should only be able to insert 2 units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible with SimPy out-of-the-box. You can, however, subclass Store and the according events to model inter-store-dependencies.

Comment: Do you know how I might do this?  I've tried overriding Store.get to return an event that takes a condition and then evaluating that condition in _do_get  (this allows me to check if the next Store has free space before executing the first Store's get).  It does solve the problem of the extra space, but I can't figure out how to "reschedule" the event in the case that the destination Store has no vacancy.  An example of what I mean is shown at: https://gist.github.com/sheridp/31516e95bee350481c1a39b1597e559f

Comment: Maybe better than what I've shown is:  rather than a generic condition, the get event could take a destination queue.  The question then is, if the event cannot succeed (because there's no room in the destination), how do I schedule the event to be re-evaluated when the destination queue experiences a get event itself?